# Visualizing historical commute times

Tags: data-visualization, histogram

I am looking for a visualization of travel times for a specific commute route (going from A to B, considering traffic of course), for example in a histogram. I would like to answer the question "how does the distribution of travel times look from A to B given I want to depart at XX"? I know that Google Maps has a feature to query a route with "arrive at" parameter but for my route is very vague (shows 30min - 1:10hr). Is there anything with more information or a data source I could query to build up the histogram myself?